# "Not Enough Space" for Autocad Inventor Installation

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, reinstall, autocad, autodesk-inventor

Today, I installed Autodesk Inventor 2016 on a new (in the last month) Windows 8.1 computer.

The install appeared to run OK, but it missed a couple of files due to my moving and renaming of the Public Documents, Downloads, Music, etc. folders.

Fine, no problem.  I just rename the folders to what Autocad is expecting:

/Public/Public Documents -> /Public/Documents.

Then I fully uninstall Autocad Inventor.

-- No Problems so far --

But then I try to reinstall.  Checking requirements... and then:

[image: Out of disk space]

It's trying to install 14.5 MB on a 0 size, 0 space disk.

What is going on here?

Comment: That does not look like a windows dialog but an autodesk dialog

Comment: It very well might be... Should I have posted on a different SE site?

Comment: You tell us if it it, if it's not a windows dialog, it won't have a process.  But the volume with 0 space also has no drive letter

Comment: It appears to be an inventor window :(

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator:

```
setup.exe /t /qb /c INSTALLDIR="C:\Autodesk\Inventor 2016" PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=P
```

or use `PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=D`

Comment: No good, it's a custom installer.